# How do I make a Beacon Ride an invisible silverfish?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On certain maps, I have seen blocks riding invisible, invincible, and silent silverfish. How would I do this with a beacon? It looks like the block is just walking around on its own. (1.8)

Comment: Something to do with FallingSand, I don't know what

Comment: Ah... yes! I should have thought of That @VolcanicTitan I think I know what to do now, but I'll have to test it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Block:"minecraft:beacon",Time:1,Riding:[{id:Silverfish,ShowParticles:0,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000},{Id:11,Amplifier:100,Duration:1000000}]}]}
```

OR for 1.9 and above

```
/summon Silverfish ~ ~ ~ {ShowParticles:0,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000},{Id:11,Amplifier:100,Duration:1000000}],Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:beacon",Time:1}]}
```

**EDIT**: Use this command on a repeating command block to reset its timer as after 30 sec, the falling sand would despawn

```
/entitydata @e[type=FallingSand] {Time:1}
```

Comment: Note that this will never function as a beacon. Beacons have to be built on pyramids

Comment: It's more functional , but for a period 30 seconds, the falling sand turns into his item form.

Comment: @iDoomfull Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer to prevent them from despawning